# How do I use multithreading on this function for a np.meshgrid of values?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, numpy, python-multithreading, numpy-ndarray

The following code generates numpy 2D lists of r and E values for the specified intervals.

```
r = np.linspace(3, 14, 10)
E = np.linspace(0.05, 0.75, 10)
r, E = np.meshgrid(r, E)
```

I am then using the following nested loop to generate output from the function *ionisationGamma* for each r and E interval value.

```
for ridx in trange(len(r)):
   z = []
   for cidx in range(len(r[ridx])):
     z.append(ionisationGamma(r[ridx][cidx], E[ridx][cidx]))
   Z.append(z)

Z = np.array(Z)
```

This loop gives me a 2D numpy array *Z*, which is my output and I am using it for a 3D graph. The problem with it is: it is taking ~6 hours to generate the output for all these intervals as there are so many values due to `np.meshgrid`. I have just discovered *multi-threading* in Python and wanted to know how I can implement this by using it. Any help is appreciated.

See below code for `ionisationGamma`

```
def ionisationGamma(r, E):
    I = complex(0.1, 1.0)
    a_soft = 1.0
    omega = 0.057
    beta = 0.0
    dt = 0.1
    steps = 10000
    Nintervals = 60
    N = 3000
    xmin = float(-300)
    xmax = -xmin
    x = [0.0]*N
    dx = (xmax - xmin) / (N - 1)
    L = dx * N

    dk = 2 * M_PI / L

    propagator = None
    in_, out_, psi0 = None, None, None

    in_ = [complex(0.,0.)] * N
    psi0 = [complex(0.,0.)] * N
    out_ = [[complex(0.,0.)]*N for i in range(steps+1)]

    overlap = exp(-r) * (1 + r + (1 / 3) * pow(r, 2))
    normC = 1 / (sqrt(2 * (1 + overlap)))
    gammai = 0.5
    qi = 0.0 + (r / 2)
    pi = 0.0
    gammai1 = 0.5
    gammai2 = 0.5
    qi1 = 0.0 - (r / 2)
    qi2 = 0.0 + (r / 2)

    pi1 = 0.0
    pi2 = 0.0


    # split initial wavepacket
    for i in range(N):
        x[i] = xmin + i * dx
        out_[0][i] = (normC) * ((pow(gammai1 / M_PI, 1. / 4.) * exp(complex(-(gammai1 / 2.) * pow(x[i] - qi1, 2.), pi1 * (x[i] - qi1)))) + (pow(gammai2 / M_PI, 1. / 4.) * exp(complex(-(gammai2 / 2.) * pow(x[i] - qi2, 2.), pi2 * (x[i] - qi2)))))
        in_[i] = (normC) * ((pow(gammai1 / M_PI, 1. / 4.) * exp(complex(-(gammai1 / 2.) * pow(x[i] - qi1, 2.), pi1 * (x[i] - qi1)))) + (pow(gammai2 / M_PI, 1. / 4.) * exp(complex(-(gammai2 / 2.) * pow(x[i] - qi2, 2.), pi2 * (x[i] - qi2)))))
        psi0[i] = in_[i]
    


    for l in range(1, steps+1):
        for i in range(N):
          propagator = exp(complex(0, -potential(x[i], omega, beta, a_soft, r, E, dt, l) * dt / 2.))
          in_[i] = propagator * in_[i];
        in_ = np.fft.fft(in_, N)
        for i in range(N):
            k = dk * float(i if i < N / 2 else i - N)
            propagator = exp(complex(0, -dt * pow(k, 2) / (2.)))
            in_[i] = propagator * in_[i]

        in_ = np.fft.ifft(in_, N)

        for i in range(N):
            propagator = exp(complex(0, -potential(x[i], omega, beta, a_soft, r, E, dt, l) * dt / 2.))
            in_[i] = propagator * in_[i]
            out_[l][i] = in_[i]
    
    initialGammaCentre = 0.0
    finalGammaCentre = 0.0

    for i in range(500, 2500 +1):
        initialGammaCentre += pow(abs(out_[0][i]), 2) * dx
        finalGammaCentre += pow(abs(out_[steps][i]), 2) * dx
    
    ionisationGamma = finalGammaCentre / initialGammaCentre
    
    return ionisationGamma

def potential(x, omega, beta, a_soft, r, E, dt, l):
    V = (-1. / sqrt((x - (r / 2)) * (x - (r / 2)) + a_soft * a_soft)) + ((-1. / sqrt((x + (r / 2)) * (x + (r / 2)) + a_soft * a_soft))) + E * x
    return V
```

Comment: can you provide `ionisationGamma` code?  you probably don't need multithreading if you can vectorize that function.

Comment: Yes, but it is a very long code. What would be the best way to share it? I have not uploaded the code on Github yet

Comment: in any case, you can clean up that `for` loop with some `zip` magic and pre-allocate `Z` using `np.empty`

Comment: I see, but will using ```zip``` affect the speed in any way?

Comment: The function itself is very long?  I find it hard to believe that a function with 2 `float` inputs would be too long to put in the question.

Comment: `zip` won't make the speed any better, but will make using `multithreading.Pool` a bit more managable if you do actually need that.

Comment: Well, it is some Physics problem and uses a lot of variables. I just rechecked the code and without comments, it is at least 70 lines

Comment: Hey, it turns out that the function ```ionisationGamma``` wasn't too long to be included in the question. Please take a look.

Comment: Well the good news is it looks like transliterated `c` code, so maybe you can throw it at `numba` without too much effort.  Don't have time now to work out making all that into `numpy` code though.

Answer (score 2):

Since the question is about how to use multiprocessing, the following code will work:

```
import multiprocessing as mp


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with mp.Pool(processes=16) as pool:
        Z = pool.starmap(ionisationGamma, arguments)
    Z = np.array(Z)
```

Where the arguments are:

```
arguments = list()
for ridx in range(len(r)):
    for cidx in range(len(r[ridx])):
        arguments.append((r[ridx][cidx], E[ridx][cidx]))
```

I am using `starmap` instead of `map`, since you have multiple arguments that you want to unpack. This will divide the arguments iterable over multiple cores, using the `ionisationGamma` function and the final result will be ordered.

However, I do feel the need to say that the main solution is not really the multiprocessing but the original function code. In `ionisationGamma` you are using several times the slow python `for` loops. And it would benefit your code a lot if you could vectorize those operations.

A second observation is that you are using many of those loops separately and it would be nice if you could separate that one big function into multiple smaller functions. Then you can time every function individually and speed up those that are too slow.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I am currently running the code with modification that you have provided to see if it reduces the time.

I have heard about Vectorization but haven't used them. Are you open to give an example of where I can possibly use Vectorization instead of a for loop inside the ```ionisationGamma``` function?

Comment: Sure, everywhere with a `for` loop is a possible candidate for a vectorization. The word itself means that instead of looping over the elements one by one, rewrite so you apply the operation to all elements at the same time. Maybe the blog: [Look Ma, No For-Loops](https://realpython.com/numpy-array-programming/), can help you out getting some ideas.

Comment: Thank you. I already had this blog opened and will hopefully be able to tell ma how I replaced the loops with vectors in my code.